# What will be the derivative of linear Transformation $L(x,y)=(x,-y)$

Tags: derivatives

Let $L$ be a map such that $L: \mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ given by $$L(x,y)=(x,-y)$$
In this question it is given that

> $DL(0,0)$=$L(x,y)$

i am not getting this how this is true?.

Solution i tried-Given linear transformation is $L(x,y)=(x,-y)$,so its derivative at point $(x,y)$ will be 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y  \end{bmatrix}=(x,-y)
$$
which is again the same transformation . But as per option the point is $(0,0)$ so the derivative will be $0$.Does the option is wrong ?insted of $L(x,y)$ there is $L(0,0)$

Comment: $dL(0,0)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^{2}$ into itself. The question was really supposed to say $L(0,0)(x,y)=L(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the definition  of derivative. The derivative of  a linear map at any point is exactly the linear map itself.

Comment: Yes, there is a mistype in the question.

Comment: Thankyou  sir,I was thinking about this.